# I am trying to implement compare() method, but it says "Object cannot be converted to Book"

Tags: java, compare, comparator

I have implemented `compare()` method in the `Book` class such that it gets sorted according to price. I have put the `Book` elements in a `TreeSet` and iterated over it, but it's not printing. Please look into the code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Demos{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       
    Book b1 = new Book("php", 200.00);
    Book b2 = new Book("java", 500.00);
    Book b3 = new Book("c", 400.00);
       
       TreeSet t = new TreeSet();
       t.add(b1);
       t.add(b2);
       t.add(b3);
       
       Iterator it = t.iterator();
       Book b;
       while(it.hasNext()){
           b = it.next();
           System.out.println(b.getName()+" "+b.getPrice());
       }       
    }
}

class Book implements Comparator{
    
    private String bname;
    private double price;
    
    public Book(String bname, double price){
        
        this.bname = bname;
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
        return bname;
    }
    
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){
        Book b1,b2;
        
         b1 = (Book)o1;
         b2 = (Book)o2;
        
        if(b1.getPrice() > b2.getPrice()){ return 1; }
        else{ return -1; }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: The error occurs exactly where the compiler tells you it occurs, and it has _nothing_ to do with the fact that you are implementing Comparator. Take the tutorial you are using. Toss it in the garbage; it is 30 years old and hopelessly out of date. Find a better one, and follow it. (The specific problem here is that you aren't using type variables; you want `Comparator<Book>`, `TreeSet<Book>`, etc.

Comment: Please refer to this example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-in-java-with-examples/.  Make your TreeSet and Comparators generic (e.g. `TreeSet<Book>`)

Comment: `Iterator#next` will return an `Object`.  You can overcome this through the use of generics as suggested by the others

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use raw types; use `TreeSet<Book>` and `Iterator<Book>`. Also, consider programming to an interface by using `NavigableSet` or `SortedSet`.
2. `TreeSet` requires implementing `Comparable`, not `Comparator`.

```
class Demos{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Book b1 = new Book("php", 200.00);
        Book b2 = new Book("java", 500.00);
        Book b3 = new Book("c", 400.00);
        NavigableSet<Book> t = new TreeSet<>();
        t.add(b1);
        t.add(b2);
        t.add(b3);
        Iterator<Book> it = t.iterator();
        Book b;
        while(it.hasNext()){
           b = it.next();
           System.out.println(b.getName()+" "+b.getPrice());
        }       
    }
}

class Book implements Comparable<Book>{
    private String bname;
    private double price;
    public Book(String bname, double price){
        this.bname = bname;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return bname;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public int compareTo(Book o){
        return Double.compare(this.price, o.price);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest `Set<Book> t = new TreeSet<>();` (or even `SortedSet<Book> t = new TreeSet<>();`). Program to the proper interface.